# Is there a way to stream video from Chrome or Safari on iOS to an html5 video tag?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, video, safari, stream

sadly, it seems that on iOS the `navigator` object on Chrome or Safari does not have `navigator.mediaDevices` or `navigator.getUserMedia`.

[image]

Is there any other known way of accessing the camera of an iPad or iPhone and stream the data into the `<video>` tag of a html page?